# How to enable agenda view in org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm trying to enable agenda-view and use agenda features under `org-mode`.
As per the org-mode manual - [Agenda section](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Agenda-files) pressing the key sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>a</kbd> `to create calendar like agenda`.

I tried this and it did not work. Then I saw the link for [Activation](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Activation) to activate agenda view and also updated the `.emacs` file as shown below

```
;; This is for org-mode agenda view activation
 '(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))
 ;; This is for key bindings to invoke agenda mode (see line-2)
 '(global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
 '(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
 '(global-set-key "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
 '(global-set-key "\C-cb" 'org-iswitchb)
```

I restarted emacs twice. But nothing seems to work. I was following this [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgizHHd7nOo) video in order to see if I can make use of agenda feature in org-mode

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are quoting those lists, so they won't actually do anything.

Try removing the leading "`'`"s like so:

```
;; This is for org-mode agenda view activation
 (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))
 ;; This is for key bindings to invoke agenda mode (see line-2)
 (global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
 (global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
 (global-set-key "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
 (global-set-key "\C-cb" 'org-iswitchb)
```

In ELISP, when a list is quoted like this, nothing inside of it gets evaluated. This is handy when you want to pass around literal lists, but serves your purpose poorly in this case.

Comment: Is there a manual for this elisp within emacs like emacs manual?

Comment: Yep! You can get to it from `C-h i`. From there, there is both a language manual, and an introduction to the language. You can also play around with it in a REPL using `M-x ielm`.

Comment: I have a filename `todo.org` seems like it does not work for it @Archenoth